# Type Stopwatch could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

I'm learning **C#** using **Xamarin Studio 4.0.3** (former MonoDevelop) on **Windows 7**.
Trying using `Stopwatch` class (only piece of code)

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
         Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();                 
    }
}
```

I get:

> Error CS0246: *The type or namespace name `Stopwatch' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*

My target framework is: Mono .NET 4.0. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Stopwatch Class should be implemented.

BTW, `DateTime` class works fine.

Question is: am I missing something (right namespace, library linking) or Stopwatch simply isn't implemented?

Comment: I just created a new console app in Xamarin Studio 4.0.3, Windows 7 64-bit and copy and pasted your code and it works fine.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 9):

Although you say that you've included the `using` directive, the error message begs to differ.

Ensure that this line is in the **same `.cs` file** as your method, at the very top:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

In Visual Studio, you can see this by clicking the icon underneath the error:

[image]

Maybe there's a similar feature in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: @ Danny Beckett As you can see my code I have added using `System.Diagnostics`. Code completion doesn't show `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` possibility. I'm using **Xamarin Studio** not VS.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Yes. They're both in Main.cs.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem similar to this just recently in Xamarin studio for Mac. I was building a PLC project for a database that had to be shared between iOS, Android and Windows Store apps.

Check the PLC project files options - right click on the project header and select Options. 
Go to build targets and unselect Silverlight 5/Windows Phone.

If it is PLC, only a subset of the framework is available to you, as it only contains functionality which can be deployed across all devices selected. Hope this helps.

Regards
Brett

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same problem.

My issue was because I had created a new project, and was trying to use Stopwatch in the new project which had no references yet.

I right clicked my new projects reference folder -> Edit References, and added a reference to System.

Saved, built and all was well in the world.

Comment: Mine was similar, it used to work on VS 2017 and then I opened in 2015 and it lost all its normal framework references. Probably a feature I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

=> Stopwatch is defined in System (in System.dll) Assemblies,

=> Check if System.dll is included in References (If not added it can be added by right clicking on references in solution explorer )

=> Add the namespace  using System.Diagnostics;

=> See more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. All using statemens and references were in place. When pointing the mouse to the parenthesis Intellisense even reacted with "Initializes a new instance of the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class" while still putting out the error message when compiling.
After saving the projects current state, closing down VS, re-opening VS and the project, the error was gone.